# Vhdl with no clk

Tags: vhdl, clock, fpga, fsm

I have a clock in my vhdl code but i don't use it , simply my process just depends on handshake when one component finishes and gets an output out , this output is in the sensitivity list of my FSM and is then becomes an input to the next component and of course its output is also in the sensitivity list of my FSM(so to know when will component finishes its computation)... and so on.
Is this method wrong ? it works in simulation and also in post-route simulation but gets me warnings like this : warning :HOLD High VIOLATION ON I WITH RESPECT TO CLK; and
warning :HOLD Low VIOLATION ON I WITH RESPECT TO CLK;

is this warnings not important or will my code damage my fpga because it doesn't depend on a clock ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning you are getting are timing violations. You get these because the tools detect that your design does not obey the necessary timing restrictions for the internal primitives.

For instance, inputs to lookup-tables (which is one of the main building-blocks inside an FPGA) need to be held for a specific time for the output to stabilize. This is very hard to guarantee when your entire timing relies only on the latencies and delays of the components themselves, and switch on a completely asynchronous basis.

Depending on your actual design (mostly the size and complexity of it), I'll wager the guess that you'll end up with a lot of very-hard-to-debug errors once you get it inside an FPGA. You'll have a much, much, much easier time using a clock. This will allow you to have a clear idea of when signals arrive where, and it will allow you to use the internal tools to check your timing. You'll also find it much easier to interface to other devices, and your system will be less susceptible to noisy inputs.

So all in all, use a clock. You (probably) wont damage your FPGA by not doing it, but a clock will save you from tons of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

your code does most probably not damage your FPGA because it doesn't depend on a clock. however, for synthesis you should always use registered (clocked) logic. without using a clock your design will not be controllable because of timing/delay/routing/fan out/... this will let your FSM behave "mysteriously" when synthesized (even if it worked in simulation).
you'll find plenty of examples for good FSM implementation style with google's help (search for *Moore* or *Mealy* FSM)

Answer (score 3):

Definitely use a clock.  And only one clock throughout the design.  This is the easiest way - the tools support this design style very well.  You can often get away with a single timing constraint, especially if your inputs are slow and synchronous to the same clock.

When you have gained experience designing this way, you can move outside of this, but be ready for more analysis, timing constraints and potentially build iterations while you learn the pitfalls of crossing clock-domains and asynchronous signals.